# Смена баннера при обновлении страницы.

Tags: javascript

Как сделать смену баннера(фонового background:url(ing..))при обновлении страницы, через js ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: используйте `Math.random()` для генерации случайного числа и в зависимости от числа выводите изображение, или же используйте куки.

Comment: Вы не пробовали завести свой атрибут у элемента и с помощью css `attr()` его считывать как адрес до картинки? А задавать атрибут легко с помощью `element.setAttribute(name, value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
var imgs = [
  'http://wallpapershome.com/images/pages/pic_h/4691.jpg',
  'http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/american-washington-state-mountains-nature-wallpapers.jpg',
  'http://cdn01.wallconvert.com/_media/conv/1/1/503-1920x1080-wallpaper-nature.jpg',
];

function getRandomFrom(array) {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[i];
}

window.onload = function() {
  var ih = document.getElementById('img-holder');
  ih.style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+ getRandomFrom(imgs) +'")';
}
```

Пример целиком [тут](https://jsbin.com/guwiqur/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, эту плюшку нужно делать через PHP. Но в JS это можно осуществить через функцию `Math.random()` и массива изображений.

```js
var images = [
  'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed979fbf8590e9bd23202689dd40ec90?s=500&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsJn.jpg?s=500&g=1',
  'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-L1ctGGvnHAU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFgk/JCsookj4K34/photo.jpg?sz=500'
];

var obj_img = document.querySelector('img');

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

obj_img.setAttribute('src', images[i]);
```

```html
<img src="">
```